# My function javascript doesn't work entirely

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My javascript function does not work entirely.

HTML :

```
<body onload="initialize();">

    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="./index.html">Accueil</a>
      <a class="active" href="./mycave.html">Ma cave</a>
      <a href="./mylist.html">Ma liste</a>
      <a href="./account.html">Mon compte</a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px" id="main">

    </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function initialize(){
        var main = document.getElementById('main');
        var database = firebase.database();
        var dbref = database.ref(uid+'/cave');

        dbref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
          snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot){
            console.info('Vin : ', childsnapshot);
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'card');
            var header = document.createElement('h1')
            header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childsnapshot.val().nom));
            div.appendChild(header);
            var viticulteur = document.createElement('p');
            viticulteur.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childsnapshot.val().viticulteur));
            div.appendChild(viticulteur);
            var nb_bouteilles = document.createElement('p');
            nb_bouteilles.setAttribute('class', 'price');
            nb_bouteilles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childsnapshot.val().number));
            div.appendChild(nb_bouteilles);
            var open = document.createElement('p');
            var open_btn = document.createElement('button');
            open_btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Voir'));
            open.appendChild(open_btn);
            div.appendChild(open);
            main.appendChild(div);
          });
        });
        console.info('Function terminated!');
      }
```

When the document load, the log console is writing only 'Function terminated'

When I execute the function in console, the console is writing 'Vin :  cn {node_: Je, ref_: Oi, index_: Pe}' and then 'Function terminated'

Could someone tell me where it might come from?

Comment: That's because the `function(snapshot){` executes when a `value` event occurs in the database, not immediately

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `dbref.once('value').then...` part gets executed once the value is gotten, asynchronously. This means the program will skip over the `dbref.once` part and continue with the execution, landing it at the `console.info` part. An eternity (to the computer) later, the `dbref.once('value').then...` part is executed, probably well after your function finished.

Basically, your `dbref.once('value').then...` function will only execute when the data is present and ready, which takes time and so it is done asynchronously and the computer will continue execution while waiting for it. You will have to plan for the function being executed later at an unknown time, so putting in placeholder values might be a good option, and the function can overwrite those defaults with the actual data.